# Azure data lake gen. 2 (adls2), api to get overall size of data stored in data lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I am looking for a way to get data about overall size of all data stored in data lake (azure data lake gen2 2 - adls2). Does anyone know how to obtain such information about data lake size (how much data is stored)? 
Tried to find appropriate API but didn't find anything so far. 
Will be thankful for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the size of all data stored in data lake gen2(not include the `File, Table, Queue` storage), you could use this [`Metrics - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/Metrics/List) REST API with [`metricnames=BlobCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftstoragestorageaccountsblobservices), specify the `timespan` with the latest one hour, e.g. now is `2019-10-14T05:48:03Z`, just use `timespan=2019-10-14T04:47:03Z/2019-10-14T05:47:03Z`, it works fine on my side.

**Sample**:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccount-name>/blobServices/default/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan=2019-10-14T04:47:03Z/2019-10-14T05:47:03Z&metricnames=BlobCapacity&api-version=2018-01-01
```

**Response**:

```
 { 
   "cost":0,
   "timespan":"2019-10-14T04:47:03Z/2019-10-14T05:47:03Z",
   "interval":"PT1H",
   "value":[ 
      { 
         "id":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/joygen2/blobServices/default/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/BlobCapacity",
         "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
         "name":{ 
            "value":"BlobCapacity",
            "localizedValue":"Blob Capacity"
         },
         "displayDescription":"The amount of storage used by the storage account’s Blob service in bytes.",
         "unit":"Bytes",
         "timeseries":[ 
            { 
               "metadatavalues":[ 

               ],
               "data":[ 
                  { 
                     "timeStamp":"2019-10-14T04:47:00Z",
                     "average":44710.0
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "namespace":"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
   "resourceregion":"eastus"
}
```

***Update***:

If you want to get the size all data including the `File, Table, Queue` storage, just use the [`UsedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftstoragestorageaccounts) metric name.

**Sample**:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccount-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan=2019-10-14T04:47:03Z/2019-10-14T05:47:03Z&metricnames=UsedCapacity&api-version=2018-01-01
```

**Response**:

```
{ 
   "cost":0,
   "timespan":"2019-10-14T04:47:03Z/2019-10-14T05:47:03Z",
   "interval":"PT1H",
   "value":[ 
      { 
         "id":"/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/UsedCapacity",
         "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
         "name":{ 
            "value":"UsedCapacity",
            "localizedValue":"Used capacity"
         },
         "displayDescription":"Account used capacity",
         "unit":"Bytes",
         "timeseries":[ 
            { 
               "metadatavalues":[ 

               ],
               "data":[ 
                  { 
                     "timeStamp":"2019-10-14T04:47:00Z",
                     "average":2559131.0
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "namespace":"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
   "resourceregion":"eastus"
}
```

Comment: is the size showed as avarage? what are units of this, is that in bytes? I would like to have overall size so preferably size of everything (files etc.) that is stored in datalake. What exactly is it showing then if it doesn't include size of any tables, files? I am not sure whether i uderstood it correctly

Comment: @bryniek Yes, you are right, the `Aggregation Type` is `Average`, it is in bytes, if you want to get the size including other storages(File, Table, Queue), check my update. To help to understand, you could check  them in your storage account in the portal -> `Metrics` directly, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqePM.png

Comment: @bryniek were you able to get this done? I see there is the ADLS SDK but I am not sure if that can get the overall size of a container. Any thoughts?