# Azure services overview

Tags: azure, api, dashboard

I have many services on the azure plateform .instead of going on azure portal always and checking which services are running i want main parameters of azure services on my dashboard like pipelines successfully ran in data factory,storage used in data lake.so is there any api which can do or fetch this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all the Azure resources have REST API exposed to get their status and key metric/attributes, so you need to write some script or code to pull these and display in your UI(may be simple javascript  based). For example to get the pipeline run details, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory)

Comment: For Data Lake, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370828/14973743)