# Get how much disk is being used in Azure Data Lake

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using [Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/) to programmatically interact with Azure.

It looks like I can get the size of a given file with

```cs
var props = await fileClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
var fileSizeInBytes = propriedades.Value.ContentLength;
```

(where `fileClient` is an instace of `DataLakeFileClient`)

`DataLakeDirectoryClient` class offers a similar API, but `ContentLength` is always zero.

I would like to know how to get the size of:

1. a directory (with `DataLakeDirectoryClient`)
2. a file system (with `DataLakeFileSystemClient`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure data lake gen. 2 (adls2), api to get overall size of data stored in data lake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367909/azure-data-lake-gen-2-adls2-api-to-get-overall-size-of-data-stored-in-data-l?rq=1)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT No it doesn't, unfortunately. I'm using the `Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake` package, not the restful api (although the package does use the restful api under the hood, as far as I know.)